# Installing Printer Hangs 13.04 : public key is not available:

Tags: apt

I am trying to install a printer.  I go to System Settings select `Printer`.  I successfully search for and find my printer by using its IP address.

Once I get to the point it choosing whether I want a driver from `gutenprint` or `local driver` I chose `gutenprint` the first time and although it said it was 'Installing driver gutenprint' asked my password but never completed.  I also hangs when selecting 'local driver'.

I have also noticed the following error when running `apt-get update`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.1 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7A4B44C2D2A2203E
```

I did try `apt-get -f install as` suggested in another thread but it made no difference.

Has anyone got any ideas that will stop me from having to re-install ubuntu?

Comment: Why do you have `http://www.openprinting.org` on your sources?

Comment: I have no memory of adding it myself, so I assume it got put their when I did the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no recollection of adding that source, please verify that your system is not compromised. Is possible that you will need to reinstall the system. For resolving any other case a simple:

```
sudo sed -i '/openprinting/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i '/openprinting/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` should fix the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a GPG : BADSIG Error so try with this:

```
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update

sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7A4B44C2D2A2203E
```

Should work.